# Where should questions about mobile devices, phones, gadgets, etc be asked?

Tags: support, allowed-topics

I was wondering where should I post slightly off-topic questions. As I've read on SuperUser its only about computer hardware and software. Do the various USB gadgets fit in the 'hardware' category? What about mobile phones, PDAs, GPSes, etc?

Comment: Google? (Joking)

Comment: see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41570/where-can-i-ask-questions-that-arent-super-user-questions

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what you're doing with the devices;

if you're talking about programming **for** devices such as phones or pda's, I'd say thats a SO question.

If its problems **using** phones or devices themselves, then the only possibility is the [electronic gadgets site](http://gadgets.stackexchange.com/). If your question is about interfacing it with a computer (sync, data transfer, etc), then you can ask it on Super User, but this is the only case.

If its problems getting USB hardware to work **with** a computer, SF is a good bet, but again, device specific forums are probably your best bet. Exception being getting data **from** a device, such as GPS, into a computer program, SO is the best place to try.

Given that you don't state any examples, I'd say put it where you think is apprpriate (given the above) and let the community/moderators migrate it or close it on a case-by-case basis.

Hope that clears things up!

Comment: the SU policy, in a nutshell, is: "problems using phones or devices *with a computer* "... getting USB devices to work with a computer is, by itself, more of a SU question than SF, unless it has to do with a pro IT environment in some way.

Comment: This question has been used as "reference" by a user on SU. I fixed the SU part to reflect the actual situation.

Comment: Your cited *gadgets* site does not exist. "Yet", as the polished up 404 error message states.