# Questions about IP Phones: Off-topic?

Tags: discussion, questions, allowed-topics

I'm trying to ascertain whether or not questions about IP phones (in my case, Cisco) are on-topic or off-topic for SuperUser. I read [this question](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/1049/where-should-questions-about-mobile-devices-phones-gadgets-etc-be-asked), which basically says:

> If its problems using phones or
>   devices themselves, then the only
>   possibility is the electronic gadgets
>   site. If your question is about
>   interfacing it with a computer (sync,
>   data transfer, etc), then you can ask
>   it on Super User, but this is the only
>   case.
>
> If its problems getting USB hardware
>   to work with a computer, SF is a good
>   bet, but again, device specific forums
>   are probably your best bet. Exception
>   being getting data from a device, such
>   as GPS, into a computer program, SO is
>   the best place to try.

However, the [Electronics StackExchange FAQ](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/faq) says:

> and it is **not about**
>
> ...
>
> - electronic devices, media players, cell phones or smart phones, except
>     insofar as designing or hacking their
>     electronic for other use

So I'm fairly confused. If I had a question about configuring or using my Cisco IP phone (just an example in this case), would it be on-topic on SuperUser (as the phone interfaces with the network and with a TFTP server to retrieve its configuration)? Would it be off-topic on Electronics? Is there another StackExchange site where I can ask these questions?

Thanks!

---

#### Example Questions:

- *How can I configure the directory of names?*
- *How would one write a service for this phone?*
- *Can SIP and SCCP be used at the same time on phone xyz?*
- *What file extensions should my configuration files have for firmware xyz?*

Comment: "If its problems getting USB hardware to work with a computer, SF is a good bet" Odd SF isn't about USB stuff at all, it's about the professional server and networking side. Either way, there isn't a Stack Exchange site for everything

Comment: There is an [Area 51 proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/12932/telephony) for a SE site that would cover this.

Comment: Thanks @Patches, I'll take a look at that proposal and see if it takes off.

Comment: Please note that it's not Electronics StackExchange. It's Electronics **Design** StackExchange.

Comment: The "electronic gadgets site" being referred to is http://gadgets.stackexchange.com which no longer exists. See: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/pruning-season/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you writing code or a library for the IP phone? Then it sounds like you're programming in which case, [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) is the place to ask.

Otherwise, then it's not on topic for Super User unless you're hooking it up with your computer.

Configuring a phone would fall out of scope unless the previously mentioned rule fell into it.

Sadly not all questions have a home on Stack Exchange.

Comment: Thanks random! :)

Comment: @squ configuring ip phones for an office is often on topic for sysadmins / server fault as well -- see http://serverfault.com/tags/asterisk